# Don't see syntax error

Tags: python, syntax

I am new to Python (keep that in mind) and am having a stab at one of the examples in a beginners' book. In it, there is a program that draws random circles on the screen. However, despite copying it out character for character, there is still a syntax error in line 19 of `circle.py`. Could someone please take the time to look through the code for me? (BTW, for a beginner, I have an OK understanding of Python. I get functions, variables and Object orientated programming, but I don't know too much more after that.)

```
 1      import pygame, random
 2  
 3      class Circle:
 4          _minimum=100;_maximum=255
 5          _colour=None
 6          _properties=[]
 7      
 8      def __init__(self,screen,width,height):
 9          self.random_colour()
10          self.draw_circle(screen,width,height)
11      
12      def draw_circle(self, screen, width, height):
13          x=random.randint(1,width)
14          y=random.randint(1,height)
15          size=random.randint(1,5)
16          self.properties=[x,y,size]
17          pygame.draw.circle(screen,self._colour,(x,y),size)
18      
19      def random_colour(self)
20          red=random.randint(self._minimum,self._maximum)
21          green=random.randint(self._minimum,self._maximum)
22          blue=random.randint(self._minimum,self._maximum)
23          self._colour=[red,green,blue]
24          
25      def clear_circle(self,screen):
26          pygame.draw_circle(screen,(0,0,0),(self._properties[0],self._properties[1],self._properties[2]
```

THANKS FOR ANY help at all.

Answer (score 5):

```
def random_colour(self)  # missing a colon
    red=random.randint(self._minimum,self._maximum)
    green=random.randint(self._minimum,self._maximum)
    blue=random.randint(self._minimum,self._maximum)
    self._colour=[red,green,blue]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for n in range(100):
    clock.tick(45)
    circles.append(circle.Circle(screen,WIDTH,HEIGHT))
    pygame.display.update()

clock.tick(1)

for c in circles:
        clock.tick(45)
        c.clear_circle(screen)
        pygame.display.update()
```

Your second if statement is incorrectly indented. Correct your indentation to 4 spaces and your syntax error will be gone.

Your indentation is also wrong in the class. Ensure scopes are properly indented as this is important to python

Comment: there is no obligation for consistent indentation between blocks.

Comment: njzk2 is right, this is not an error. It's of course a good idea to use a consistent amount of spaces per indent level, but Python views indentation levels as relative to the previous and next lines only.

Comment: Agreed.  Within each block the indentation must be consistent, however the indentation can be different between two different blocks.  Python might not complain, but other developers will.